# Raiils: Respond and close HTTP request, but run some more of an action without a queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers

(I know it's not best practice, but I'm still wondering if there's a way to do it)

I have a controller action that has a moderately long-running part (~30 seconds). I'd like to respond to the HTTP request (so that it closes), run the part that takes time, then use something like Pusher to notify that it's successful (last part is done, but here for context).

Something like this:

```
def some_action
  if action_should_succeed?
    head :no_content
  else
    render text: "Some error message", status: :unproccessable_entity
  end

  # Connection is now closed and the client has received the HTTP response

  do_long_thing()

  send_notification()
end
```

I know that the "correct" way to do this is to have a job queue and a worker process, but while this is the only action with this kind of delayed processing, I'd prefer not to add all that. Any ideas?